# How to check http methods supported by the tomcat

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat

In below code sample am getting the http method **get** is used as reQuest now want to know what are all the http methods my tomcat server support.Please help to find this.

**GET / HTTP/1.0**

```
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.6 (X11; I; Linux 2.2.6-15apmac ppc)
Host: zink.demon.co.uk:1126
Accept: image/gif, */*
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to know this unless you ask the server which methods it supports.

Usually this is done with the [`OPTIONS`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html) HTTP method, but not all web servers support it. Also, it applies to a specific URL, not the whole server.